# Bash - source <script> stopped searching in current directory with bash 4.1.2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script that basically does something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PREV=`pwd`
cd $1
source another.sh
cd $PREV
```

This used to work with bash 3.2.5, but stopped working with bash 4.1.2.

```
./this.sh <dir>
/home/this.sh: line 4: source: another.sh: file not found
```

It works if I change *source another.sh* to *source ./another.sh*, which I assume would be a better practice anyways. But I am curious what has changed in the new bash version.

Thanks much!

Comment: BTW, a few notes: `cd $PREV` is needless, if that's the entirety of your script -- its changes to the current directory are thrown away when it exits automatically as long as it's run as a subprocess rather than sourced. Also, quote your expansions: `cd "$1"`; `cd "$PREV"`; also, consider using lower-case names for your variables, per naming convention specified in fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (keep in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace).

Comment: Also, it's good form to abort if a `cd` fails to run -- otherwise, you need to think about what your script will do otherwise if the remaining commands are run in a different directory than intended. Thus, `cd "$1" || exit` is a typical approach, or `cd "$1" || { retval=$?; echo "could not cd to $1" >&2; exit "$retval"; }` if you want to be explicit (though `cd` itself should print to stderr on failure).

Comment: As long as you're being robust you should use `pushd` instead of `cd`, thusly: `set -e ; pushd "$1" >/dev/null ; set +e ; source another.sh ; popd >/dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change between 3.2-release and 4.0-alpha, notated as such in the changelog:

> ```
> ggg. Fixed a bug that caused a shell running in Posix mode to search $PWD for
>      a file specified as an argument to source/. when the file was not found
>      in $PATH.
> ```

...and also [previously discussed on the mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/bug-bash-gnu/2009-07/msg00027.html).

---

Note that the bash 3.2 documentation for `source` specified its behavior as follows:

> source: source filename [arguments]
>
> Read and execute commands from FILENAME and return.  The pathnames
>      in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.  If any
>     ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters when
>     FILENAME is executed.

This specifies rather clearly that PATH is to be used to find the file to run if not absolute, with no indication that the current working directory should be referenced; thus, its behavior went above and beyond the specification; thus, removing it broke no documented behavior.

---

Finally, [from the POSIX specification for the `.` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/dot.html):

> If file does not contain a slash, the shell shall use the search path specified by PATH to find the directory containing file. Unlike normal command search, however, the file searched for by the dot utility need not be executable. If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be considered a syntax error.

Thus, the new behavior is properly POSIX-compliant.

Comment: How do I check if bash is running in posix mode? Because I tried setting posix mode with 'set -o posix' and 'set +o posix'. The script worked on 3.5.2, and did not on 4.1.2, regardless of setting posix mode.

Comment: I figured it out. I was invoking the script with '/bin/sh', which enables posix mode.

Comment: ...enables POSIX mode if `/bin/sh` is provided by bash (or zsh, or another heavily extended shell with a POSIX mode), or just flat out uses a closer-to-POSIX shell, if you're on Debian/Ubuntu/etc., where `/bin/sh` is dash.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually correct behavior. From the POSIX specifications for `sh`:

"dot - execute commands in the current environment"

"If file does not contain a slash, the shell shall use the search path  specified by PATH to find the directory containing file."

"Some older implementations searched the current directory for the file, even if the value of PATH disallowed it. This behavior was omitted from this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 due to concerns about introducing the susceptibility to trojan horses..."